# Lumia 930 bought from Amazon could not update to Denim?

Tags: lumia-denim-update, nokia-lumia-930

I am currently living in U.S. Last November, I bought a Lumia 930 through Amazon. The phone was tagged as international version. However, I believed it is a Hong Kong version phone since it shows '000-HK' in the extra-info.

Yesterday, Microsoft announced the Lumia Denim was available for Lumia 930 in Hong Kong. But it has been one day, and the phone could not find any new update.

Does anyone know if it is anything wrong with my phone? Thank you guys.

Comment: What build do you have installed already?

Comment: Just because an update has been announced for a specific model, it doesn't mean they all can get the update at the same time - be patient and the update may become available in a few days.